# Comparing two text files and display unique words in java

Tags: java

I have two text files. I have to develop a java program which compares the two files and find unique words. I have tried a few methods but didn’t work. Example:

test1.txt:

```
I am a robot. My name is Sofia.
```

test2.txt:

```
Hello  I am a man. My name is Alex
```

Output:

```
Hello robot man Sofia Alex
```

I approach was like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test1.txt"));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("test2.txt"));

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
         String test;

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String next = input.next();


           }
         System.out.println("arraylist" + al);

        while (scan.hasNext()) {

                test = scan.next();
               a2.add(test);

           }
         System.out.println("arraylist2" + a2);

    for( int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < a2.size(); j++){
            if(al.get(i).equals(a2.get(j))){
          break;}
          else{
          System.out.println(al.get(i));break;
          }
    }
    }    

}
}
```

Comment: `I have tried few methods` ... please show us your code.  Your question would take quite a bit of coding, which might be too broad.

Comment: The simplest would be to use `Set`s but without seing your "methods"... I won't show mine

Comment: @AxelH post updated.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated

Comment: I would suggest a `Set` instead of a `List`, you don't need to store the same word every time. Then, set everything in lowercase, it would be simpler to compare `Man` and `man`. I quick solution would be use `List.removeAll(Collection)`, the remaining values are unique in both text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this is a quick and dirty approach and pretty inefficient. Furthermore I dont know your exact requirements (full stops? Upper/lowercase?).

Also take into account that this program doesn't check which list is longer. But this should give you a good hint:

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test1.txt"));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("test2.txt"));

        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            list1.add(input.next());
        }

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            list2.add(scan.next());
        }

        // iterate over list 1
        for (int i = list1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // if there is a occurence of two identical strings
            if (list2.contains(list1.get(i))) {
                // remove the String from list 2
                list2.remove(list2.indexOf(list1.get(i)));
                // remove the String from list 1
                list1.remove(i);
            }
        }

        // merge the lists
        list1.addAll(list2);

        // remove full stops
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            list1.set(i, list1.get(i).replace(".", ""));
        }
        System.out.println("Unique Values: " + list1);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you help me for another thing?  i want to make all words of the files to lowercase and then compare .

Comment: replace `list1.add(input.next();` with `list1.add(input.next().toLowerCase());`. Do the same with list2.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions are the text file contains only (.) as sentence terminator.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
       { 

        // Skipping reading from file and storing in string

        String stringFromFileOne = "I am a robot. My name is Sofia.";
        String stringFromFileTwo = "Hello  I am a man. My name is Alex";

        Set<String> set1 = Arrays.asList(stringFromFileOne.split(" "))
                .stream()
                .map(s -> s.toLowerCase())
                .map(m -> m.contains(".") ? m.replace(".", "") : m)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Set<String> set2 = Arrays.asList(stringFromFileTwo.split(" "))
                .stream()
                .map(s -> s.toLowerCase())
                .map(m -> m.contains(".") ? m.replace(".", "") : m)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        List<String> uniqueWords;

        if (set1.size() > set2.size()) {
            uniqueWords = getUniqueWords(set2, set1);
        } else {
            uniqueWords = getUniqueWords(set1, set2);
        }
        System.out.println("uniqueWords:" + uniqueWords);
    }

    private static List<String> getUniqueWords(Set<String> removeFromSet, Set<String> iterateOverSet) {
        List<String> uniqueWords;
        Set<String> tempSet = new HashSet<String>(removeFromSet);
        removeFromSet.removeAll(iterateOverSet);
        uniqueWords = iterateOverSet.stream().filter(f -> !tempSet.contains(f) && !f.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        uniqueWords.addAll(removeFromSet);
        return uniqueWords;
    }
```

Comment: You could juste replace without checking if there is a `.`, it is probably more efficient to search and replace in one method that do it probably in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use guava library which gives you difference between two sets.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

public class WordTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordTest wordTest = new WordTest();

        Set<String> firstFileWords = wordTest.getAllWords("E:\\testing1.txt");
        Set<String> secondFileWords = wordTest.getAllWords("E:\\testing2.txt");
        Set<String> diff = Sets.difference(firstFileWords, secondFileWords);
        Set<String> diff2 = Sets.difference(secondFileWords, firstFileWords);

        System.out.println("Set 1: " + firstFileWords);
        System.out.println("Set 2: " + secondFileWords);
        System.out.println("Difference between " + "Set 1 and Set 2: " + diff);
        System.out.println("Difference between " + "Set 2 and Set 1: " + diff2);
    }

    public Set<String> getAllWords(String path) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        Set<String> wordList = new HashSet<>();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ,.;:\"");
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    wordList.add(st.nextToken());
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return wordList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class FileComparision {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        HashSet<String> uniqueSet=new HashSet<String>();

        //split the lines based on the delimiter and add it to set
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test1.txt"));
        String line; 
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).forEach(word->uniqueSet.add(word) ); ;
        } 
        reader.close();

        reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test2.txt"));          
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).forEach(word->{
                if(!uniqueSet.contains(word)) {
                    uniqueSet.add(word) ;
                }else {
                    uniqueSet.remove(word);
                }

            });

        } 
        reader.close(); 
        //to remove unnecessary characters
        //uniqueSet.remove(".");
        System.out.println(uniqueSet);



    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 public static String readFile(String fileName)throws Exception 
      { 
        String data = ""; 
        data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName))); 
        return data; 
      } 

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      { 
        String data = readFileAsString("C:\\Users\\pb\\Desktop\\text1.txt"); 
        String data1 = readFileAsString("C:\\Users\\pb\\Desktop\\text2.txt"); 
       String array[]=data.split(" ");
       String array1[]=data1.split(" ");


                   for(int i=0;i<=array1.length-1;i++){
                       if(data.contains(array1[i])){

                       }else{
                           System.out.println(array1[i]);
                       }
                   }


                   for(int i=0;i<=array.length-1;i++){
                       if(data1.contains(array[i])){

                       }else{
                           System.out.println(array[i]);
                       }
                   }


      }
```

Comment: I have never seen anyone using an empty `if` block like this, just use the opposite condition ...

Comment: yes  off course its just an idea, lot of code can be optimized in this.
if it helps then anyone using it can add the opposite condition and replace if-else block